# Does Thailand still refuse travelers for not having 6 month's passport validity from their entry date?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, thailand

According to [the website of the Thai Embassy in Stockholm](http://thaiembassy.se/en/visa/general-information/) (emphasis mine):

> For Swedish passport holder, and wish to stay in Thailand for no more than 30 days, **your passport has to be valid for at least 6 months when you enter Thailand. (according to immigration law).** The immigration officer can make an exemption for you if your passport is only valid during your stay in Thailand. We do strongly recommend that your passport has a validity of at least 6 months. You shall also check with your airline for other requirement.

Similar information is stated on the [website of the Thai Embassy in Tel Aviv](http://www.thaiembassy.org/telaviv/en/services/685/17388-Entry-to-Thailand.html) (emphasis mine):

> Can I enter Thailand without a visa?
>
> Nationals of Israel are eligible to travel to Thailand, for tourism purpose, with the exemption of visa and are permitted to stay in Thailand for a period of not exceeding 30 days.
>
> However, **please make sure that you are in possession of a passport valid for at least 6 months**, a round-trip air ticket, and adequate finances equivalent to at least US$1,000 per person or US$2,000 Baht per family.  Otherwise you may be inconvenienced upon entry into the country.

Similar information is echoed by other countries informing their citizens. The [UK's Foreign Office website](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/thailand/entry-requirements) states (emphasis mine):

> Your **passport must have at least 6 months’ validity remaining from your date of entry into Thailand**. Entry to Thailand is normally refused if you have a passport which is damaged or has pages missing.

[The US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Thailand.html) has similar information, but only uses *recommend* rather than phrasing it as a strict requirement:

> PASSPORT VALIDITY: 6 months from date of entry recommended

---

I've searched through and English version of [the Immigration Act, B.E. 2522](http://library.siam-legal.com/thailand-immigration-act-b-e-2522/), but I haven't found it. I may have overlooked it, but it may also be one of those unwritten rules.

So my question is whether this requirement is (still) enforced. Are there any stories of people being refused entry solely for not having a passport with 6 months validity remaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date. [***With the following exceptions:***]
>
>   - Nationals of Thailand are allowed to enter with an expired passport.
>   - When nationals of Thailand travel with a Certificate of Identity or a temporary passport, it must be valid on arrival.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>       residents of Thailand must be valid on arrival.
>   - Passports issued to nationals of Argentina, Australia,
>       Austria, Bahrain, Belgium, Brazil, Brunei Darussalam,
>       Canada, Chile, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France,
>       Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Ireland
>       (Rep.), Israel, Italy, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait,
>       Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Monaco, Netherlands,
>       New Zealand, Norway, Oman, Peru, Philippines, Poland,
>       Portugal, Qatar, Russian Fed., Singapore, Slovakia,
>       Slovenia, South Africa, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey,
>       USA and United Arab Emirates must be valid for the period
>       of intended stay.
>   - British passports must be valid for the period of intended
>       stay.
>   - Hong Kong (SAR China) passports must be valid for the
>       period of intended stay.
>   - Macao (SAR China) passports must be valid for the period of
>       intended stay.
>   - When applying for a visa on arrival, passports issued to
>       nationals of Bulgaria, Cyprus, Ethiopia, Fiji, Georgia,
>       Kazakhstan, Malta, Mexico, Nauru, Papua New Guinea, Saudi
>       Arabia, Uzbekistan and Vanuatu must be valid for a minimum
>       of 30 days from the arrival date.
>   - When applying for a visa on arrival, Chinese Taipei (on the
>       cover: Republic of China Taiwan) passports must be valid
>       for a minimum of 30 days from the arrival date.
>   - When nationals of Algeria, Argentina, Australia, Austria,
>       Bahamas, Belgium, Brazil, Brunei Darussalam, Colombia,
>       Czechia, Denmark, Djibouti, Finland, France, Guinea,
>       Hungary, Iceland, Korea (Dem. People's Rep.),
>       Liechtenstein, Madagascar, Netherlands, Norway, Palau,
>       Paraguay, Philippines, Seychelles, Sri Lanka, Sudan,
>       Sweden, Trinidad and Tobago, USA and Uruguay travel with an
>       emergency passport, it must be valid for a minimum of 30
>       days from the arrival date.
>   - When nationals of Argentina, Belize, Benin, Bulgaria,
>       Canada, Ecuador, Finland, Germany, Hungary, Italy, Jordan,
>       Kenya, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Madagascar, Malawi, Maldives,
>       Namibia, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Sao Tome and
>       Principe, Suriname, Switzerland, Turkey, United Arab
>       Emirates, Venezuela and Zambia travel with a temporary
>       passport, it must be valid for a minimum of 30 days from
>       the arrival date.
>   - When applying for a visa on arrival, normal passports
>       issued to nationals of Bhutan, India and Romania must be
>       valid for a minimum of 30 days from the arrival date.
>   - When applying for a visa on arrival, normal passports
>       issued to nationals of China (People's Rep.) must be valid
>       for a minimum of 30 days from the arrival date.

As such, the Thai embassy website is wrong regarding Swedes (embassy sites often are): only a passport valid during the stay is needed, except for emergency passports, which must have 30 days on entry.

Comment: Does you first bullet point overrule the others? It seems contradictory the way it's spaced now.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica No, it means that, other than what's listed in the other bullet points, the first one applies

Comment: Thanks. Do we know where TIMATIC gets its information? Do the countries supply it themselves? I should point out that the linked website is not the Swedish MFA, it's the Thai Embassy in Sweden. And the same is listed by the Thai Embassy in Tel Aviv (and those are just the ones I checked, many others probably have it on their site). There's still some doubt which is right (especially when it comes to how Thailand deals with this in practice, rather than the airlines).

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica As I know TIMATIC's sourcing manager, I can confirm they get it directly from national authorities. While TIMATIC does have some outdated/incomplete info (I "collect" such for IATA on a voluntary basis), embassies are **far worse**. And remember airlines get heavy fines for transporting inadmissible passengers, so TIMATIC seeks to provide info on real-time de facto airport practice as much as possible.

Comment: `No, it means that, other than what's listed in the other bullet points, the first one applies` I added an grammatical edit to make this point clear.   You or other moderators can have a look.